# V-for doesn't output props despite correctly passing in props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to do a simple thing, which doesn't work because I don't know why.

So in parent, App.vue, component, I have

```
data() {
    return {
      servers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          status: offline
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          status: offline
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          status: offline
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          status: offline
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          status: offline
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

I am then passing it down to Servers.vue `<servers :servers="servers"></servers>`.

In Servers.vue I have simple

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" v-for="i in servers">Server</li>
</ul>
```

which does not output anything. Nothing at all, even though there is no error.

Yes, I am doing `props: ["servers"],`.

Any idea what to do?

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now...

edit: corrected that silly typo in code, still nothing

edit 2: here's all of the code https://github.com/thenathurat/exercise-7

Comment: `'serves' !== 'servers'`

Comment: Fixed, still nothing

Comment: Add a key: `<li class="list-group-item" v-for="server in servers" :key="server.id">Server</li>`

Comment: Added, still nothing
`<li class="list-group-item" v-for="server in servers" :key="server.id">Server</li>`

Comment: Ok, I see you injected the props correctly. Strange it does not work.

Comment: Everything looks fine from the code you have provided. The issue lies elsewhere, which will be very difficult for us to diagnose unless you can provide a fiddle or something.

Comment: Here's the code https://github.com/thenathurat/exercise-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your GitHub repository, please modify the `data()` function of **Servers.vue** as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
      servers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          status: 'offline'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          status: 'offline'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          status: 'offline'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          status: 'offline'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          status: 'offline'
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

This will make your code work and here is a screenshot of the execution program:

[image]